# Prevent program of sending Invoke error for CircularProgressBar

Tags: c#, winforms

I have chosen a CircularProgressBar into my form1 which shows the local time of the city and it works fine. But when I open form2 and I want to use form1.Controls, I have to create an object of form1 to use the controls. But when I want to create an object, it shows an error all the time. I will send my code and the error messages, as well.

```
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{

    if (!this.IsHandleCreated)
        this.CreateControl();

    CircularTime.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        CircularTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
        CircularTime.SubscriptText = DateTime.Now.ToString("tt");
    });
}
```

And the error :

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.'

Any suggestion would be appreciate.

***UPDATE***

```
public Main_Form()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    timer.Start();
}
```

`CircularTime` is a control on the form, of type `CircularProgressBar` (from the NuGet package of the same name). CircularProgressBar works exactly like ProgressBar but with a circle shape.

After adding the NuGet package, I added CircularProgressBar.dll from the package folder into the toolbox, then I dragged and dropped one into my form.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: @Richardissimo I just added up

Comment: @Richardissimo CircularTime is an object of CircularProgressBar that is a control in WindowsFormsApplication which you can add so easily with install the NugetPackages from solution explorer. CicularProgressBar works exactly like ProgressBar but with a circle shape, and CircularTime is the name of CircularProgressBar which I added in my forms.

Comment: That's a dangerous timer since the form can't dispose it.  Declare it at the form level, and use a WinForm's Timer instead.

Comment: @Richardissimo Yeah after adding NugetPackages, I added CircularProgressBar.dll from Package folder into my toolbox, then I draged and droped into my form and used it as I described it above.

Comment: "in your question" means "in your question", not "in the comments". I will edit it for you.

Comment: @Richardissimo Thank you. Sorry for it. I'm not expert in it.

Comment: @LarsTech I did what you've said. I added a Timer from toolbox and replaced that codes from InitializeComponente() into Timer_Tick and it works fine.

Comment: CircularTime,Refresh()

Answer (score 1):

From my comment:

That's a dangerous timer since the form can't dispose it. Declare it at the form level, and use a WinForm's Timer instead, which will resolve your threading problem:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

public Main_Form()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  CircularTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
  CircularTime.SubscriptText = DateTime.Now.ToString("tt");
}
```